# Trying to understand a recursive function to reverse a string

Tags: c, recursion

I can't understand why this code works. Do characters in the string get removed because they are being passed by reference? I see no decrement or such, so I find that really confusing. Also, is the string getting reversed because of the lifo nature of the function call stack?

```
 void reverse(const char * const sPtr){
   if('\0' == sPtr[0])
     return;
     else{
       reverse(&sPtr[1]);
       putchar(sPtr[0]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: There are some good explanations below, but I wanted to mention one thing: the string itself is not being changed in this code.  It's just printing it in reverse on character at a time (via `putchar()`).

Comment: Which is also one of the primary reasons recursive functions should be avoiding if a procedural solution is available -- confusion. And this is as simple as it gets. The complexity goes up by an order of magnitude if there is a 2nd recursive call within the function. Additionally, each recursive call is a completely separate function call which requires setting up a separate function stack. (but there are some cases where the recursive solutions provides a much more elegant solution) Weight the benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is being *removed*. But the pointer being passed into the function is changed, in this expression:

```
&sPtr[1]
```

… which is equivalent to

```
sPtr + 1
```

So each recursive call increments the pointer by one, thus causing the recursive calls to traverse your `char` array.

As for why this causes the reversal of the string, the LIFO nature of the stack is indeed the reason. Your function *first* calls itself recursively and *then* outputs the current character using `putchar`. This has thus the effect of outputting the characters in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Care to elaborate on why &sPtr[1] equals sPtr +1?

Comment: @Impasse Because that’s how arrays are defined in C: `x[i]` is defined to be the same as `*(x + i)`, therefore `&x[i]` is the same as `&*(x + i)`, and the `&*` cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

If you input "abc", the call stack will look something like this.

```
reverse("abc")
    reverse("bc")
        reverse("c")
        print("c")
    print("b")
print("a")
```

So each reverse call calls itself with the same string, but first character excluded, and THEN prints the first character in the string.

> Do characters in the string get removed because they are being passed by reference?

There is no call by reference in C. Pointers kind of emulate it, but everything in C is passed by value. Besides, the type of the pointer `const char * const` says two things. First, the pointer will not get reassigned to point at anything else, but more importantly, it also says that the string will not be changed. Try adding the line `sPtr[0] = 'a'` somewhere, and you'll get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't get deleted.

In every recursive call, you want to progress to the next character, which is done here:

```
reverse(&sPtr[1]); // you pass a parameter the 1st character of where you point to now
```

Answer (score 1):

After the last `reverse(&sPtr[1])` there will be stacked 3 calls of putchar.

Each call of `reverse` grows the pointer with 1, so the stacked calls will be --supposing the input string is made of 3 characters--

```
CURRENT FRAME -- *(ptr+3) is NULL
putchar(*(ptr+2))
putchar(*(ptr+1))
putchar(*(ptr+0))
```